# How to detect in Chrome either the javascript is executed from a document/ from extension or from javascript console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

How to detect in Chrome if the javascript is executed from the Chrome DevTools Javascript console?

Smth. like:

```
if(...) {
  alert('from document')
} else if (...) {
  alert('from console') 
} else if (...) {
  alert('from extension')
} else if (...) {
  alert('from app')
} else {
  alert('another source')
}
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, why would you want to do that? What's the real-world problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: is it possible to extend chromium to allow access **only** from javascript console (not from js in an html document) to chrome tabs (so, not only from extensions or apps, but also manually from the js console, but still prohibit access to tabs from documents)?

Comment: @static The [`chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) API is only available to extension processes. The only way to access this API from the devtools is by opening the devtools for an extension page (e.g. popup, options, background page).

Comment: great! thank you, I thought it is only possible to call the chrome.tabs within the extension or app, now I can use console to (from an extension page)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this will work:

1) in html

```
unlockMyConsoleCode = false; // global variable

function workOnlyFromConsole() {
   if (!unlockMyConsoleCode)  return 'I'am working only from console';

  // do some one only from console

}
```

2) in devtools console:

```
unlockMyConsoleCode = true;
workOnlyFromConsole();
```

Also, maybe there is a difference between a variable 'this' of html and devTools console.

1) in html:

```
function outputThisVar() { 
   console.log(this) 
}

outputThisVar();
```

2) in devtools console:

```
outputThisVar();
```